# graph API sharepoint Copy a DriveItem

Tags: file, sharepoint, graph, directory, copy

I haven't been able to find a similar post anywhere. Has anyone successfully utilized this HTTP Request from the graph API.
`POST /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/copy`

I'm using Power Automate/Flow to attempt to copy the contents of one SharePoint folder to another and from what I'm reading any folder or file has an itemID but all the lookups available including the builtin SharePoint ones and other Graph API GET requests all return a file path looking thing as an ID
("/Shared+Documents" as an example). When I use this ID I get an "is not valid"

```
"message": The expression \"sites('tenant.sharepoint.com,41042aef-6014-4861-9bfb-80243b97850e,6dd019c6-141e-49d1-ab00-7424eb5730b2')/drive/items/Shared+Documents/copy\" is not valid."
```

Where as when I do the same request using a junk guid like this below I get the error message `"The resource could not be found"` which tells me my request was valid and met the API calls requirements but simply didn't exist
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenant.sharepoint.com,41042aef-6014-4861-9bfb-80243b97850e,6dd019c6-141e-49d1-ab00-7424eb5730b2/drive/items/c98f100b-de82-441b-8ec6-400b448ec696/copy

`"message": "The resource could not be found."`

Can anyone tell me how to get the itemID that meets this requirement so I can utilize this API call or Highlight where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

@Chris,

Below is the [copy endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
POST /drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/copy
```

In the endpoint, it require the itemid of the target item. Itemid is a unique guid of the item.

How to get the item id? For example we only know the path of the folder:

[image]

We can get its id through below endpoint:

```
/drive/root:/{item-path}
```

[image]

BR